# How to fix "Cannot read property 'match' of undefined" error in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, string

I'm new to Node JS and am trying to set up a basic application that fetches my inbox (outlook) contents in JSON format. I tried using match function to filter the data based on subject but I keep getting this error -

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'match' of null
    at WriteStream.<anonymous> (C:\Users\52025088\Desktop\EMAIL APPROVAL DEMO\Outlook NODE\OFFICE365_NJS_DEMO.js:44:29)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:273:13)
    at WriteStream.emit (events.js:182:13)
    at lazyFs.open (internal/fs/streams.js:278:10)
    at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:141:20)
```

I tried using other string functions as well but keep getting similar errors.

**I am able to print 'json.value[i].Subject' in console but cannot use it in match function.**

/*Request portion*/

```
request(options, function(err, res, body) {  
let json = JSON.parse(body);

console.log(err);

var fileName = 'abc.html';
var html = '';
var stream = fs.createWriteStream(fileName);


stream.once('open', function(fd) {
for (var i = 0; i < json.value.length-1; i++){





        if(json.value[i].Subject.match(/Action Required/)){

            var dom = new JSDOM(json.value[i].Body.Content);

            console.log(json.value[i].Subject);

            html = html + '<br/>' + json.value[i].Subject + '<a href=' + dom.window.document.querySelector("a") + 'target="_top">Approve</a><br/><br/>';

        }       
}
html = '<!DOCTYPE html>'
   + '<html><head>' + "List Of Pending Items" + '</head><body>' + html + '</body></html>';
stream.end(html);
});
```

});

```
C:\Users\52025088\Desktop\EMAIL APPROVAL DEMO\Outlook NODE>node OFFICE365_NJS_DEMO.js
null
FW: Action Required: Approval of Earned Leave Absence Request for Vishnu Babu from 2019-03-26 to 2019-03-26
FW: Action Required: Approval of Earned Leave Absence Request for Vishnu Babu from 2019-05-08 to 2019-05-08
C:\Users\52025088\Desktop\EMAIL APPROVAL DEMO\Outlook NODE\OFFICE365_NJS_DEMO.js:44
                        if(json.value[i].Subject.match(/Action Required/)){
                                                 ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'match' of null
    at WriteStream.<anonymous> (C:\Users\52025088\Desktop\EMAIL APPROVAL DEMO\Outlook NODE\OFFICE365_NJS_DEMO.js:44:29)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:273:13)
    at WriteStream.emit (events.js:182:13)
    at lazyFs.open (internal/fs/streams.js:278:10)
    at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:141:20)
```

I expect the match function to work so that I can filter based on Subject (json.value[i].Subject) but I guess I missed out something.

However I am able to get results if I hard code some string to compare with the Subject.

```
if(json.value[i].Subject == 'FW: Action Required: Approval of Earned Leave Absence Request for Vishnu Babu from 2019-03-26 to 2019-03-26'){

                var dom = new JSDOM(json.value[i].Body.Content);

                console.log(json.value[i].Subject);

                html = html + '<br/>' + json.value[i].Subject + '<a href=' + dom.window.document.querySelector("a") + 'target="_top">Approve</a><br/><br/>';

            }

C:\Users\52025088\Desktop\EMAIL APPROVAL DEMO\Outlook NODE>node OFFICE365_NJS_DEMO.js
null
FW: Action Required: Approval of Earned Leave Absence Request for Vishnu Babu from 2019-03-26 to 2019-03-26
```

Comment: We can't help you without an example of the JSON. From the error, clearly `json_value[i].Subject` is `null`, but we can't tell you *why* without the JSON.

Comment: "*I tried using other string functions as well but keep getting similar errors.*" because you are not operating on a string but `undefined`. That's what the error message is telling you when you do `json.value[i].Subject.match()` the `json.value[i].Subject` part evaluates to `undefined`, which doesn't have a `.match()` method. Examine your data and see if `.Subject` is the correct property to use. Note that it's case sensitive.

Comment: Thanks for your replies. The JSON is quite large. I am able to print json.value[i].Subject on console.

Comment: The JSON may be large, but it's entirely possible to show us *its structure* and/or a trimmed-down version of it. See: [mcve]

Comment: Hi TJ. I am able to run if I use a relational operator (==) to compare 'Subject' with a hard coded String (Updated the question). Thanks for your response.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your if in:

```
const subject = json.value[i].Subject; // to make it shorter

if(subject && subject.match(/Action Required/)) {
  // your code
}
```

Using this if condition you'll use `.match()` function only if `json.value[i].Subject` is defined.